# In Python CGI create select menu using list variable

Tags: python, html

Is there any convenient/standard way to generate html select menu using list variable?
For example I have list variable `elements=['aaa','zzz','sss']` 
And need to generate drop down select menu using this variable:

```
<select name="dropdown" >
<option value="aaa">aaa</option>
<option value="zzz"> zzz </option>
<option value="sss"> sss </option>
</select> <br />
```

In Perl for example I can use  CGI module and just specify :

```
 popup_menu(-name=>'dropdown', -values=>['NULL',@elements])
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe this would work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548474/python-html-generator

Comment: Lots of suggestions from this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521621/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-html-from-python  It's mostly is suggestions for template engines, but it sounds like Genshi has a direct HTML generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def makeSelect(name,values):
    SEL = '<select name="{0}">\n{1}</select>\n'
    OPT = '<option value="{0}">{0}</option>\n'
    return SEL.format(name, ''.join(OPT.format(v) for v in values))
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thank you, exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please feel free to tag it as the solution! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a native markup generator, but this library looks promising.

[markup.py](http://markup.sourceforge.net/)

**EDIT:** It looks like it hasn't been worked on since 2007

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Hugh's answer a bit, someone might need a selected option:

```
def makeSelect(name, values, selectedValue=None):
  SEL = '<select name="{0}">\n{1}</select>\n'
  OPT = '<option value="{0}"{1}>{0}</option>\n'
  return SEL.format(name, ''.join(OPT.format(v, " SELECTED" if v==selectedValue else "") for v in values))
```