# How to generate a static .html with python

Tags: python, html, plotly, static-html

I'm looking for a python solution to create a static .html that can be sent out via email, either attached or embedded in the email (ignore this latter option if it requires a lot more work). I do not have requirements for what regards the layout of the .html. The focus here is in identifying the less painful solution for to generate an offline .html.

A potential solution could be along the lines of the following pseudo-code.

```
from some_unknown_pkg import StaticHTML

# Initialise instance
newsletter = StaticHTML()

# Append charts, tables and text to blank newsletter.
newsletter.append(text_here)
newsletter.append(interactive_chart_generated_with_plotly)
newsletter.append(more_text_here)
newsletter.append(a_png_file_loaded_from_local_pc)



# Save newsletter to .html, ready to be sent out.
newsletter.save_to_html('newsletter.html')
```

Where `'newsletter.html'` can be opened in a whatever browser. Just to provide a bit more context, this .html is supposed to be sent out to a few selected people inside my company and contains sensible data. I'm using plotly to generate interactive charts to be inserted in the .html.

Answer (score 3):

Start your python module with by importing `sys` module and redirect stdout to `newsletter.html`

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('newsletter.html','w')
```

This will redirect any output generated to the html file. Now, just use the `print` command in python to transmit html tags to the file. For eg try:

```
print "<html>"
print "<p> This is my NewsLetter </p>"
print "</html>"`
```

This code snippet will create a basic HTML file. Now, you can open this file in any browser. For sending email you can use `email` and `smtplib` modules of python.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748559/generating-html-documents-in-python)

Seems package in that answer is exactly you want. Docs: http://www.yattag.org/

Another pretty nice package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html).

Answer (score 1):

The Dominate package looks like it provides a simple and intuitive way to create HTML pages. https://www.yattag.org/