# Trying to substitute one variable for another before writing to an HTML File

Tags: python

I have a python program that reads a csv file, makes some changes, then writes to an HTML file. The issue is a block of code where I'm trying to search for a string assigned to one variable, then replace it with another string assigned to another variable. I am able to read a line in the csv file that looks like this:

```
Link:,www.google.com
```

And I am successful in writing an html file with the following:

```
<tr><td>Link:</td><td><a href="https://www.google.com">www.google.com</a></td></tr>
```

Essentially I want to go further with an added step to find www.google.com between the anchor tags and replace it with "GOOGLE".

I've researched 'find and replace' functions built into python, and I came up with the substitution function inside the regular expressions module (re.sub()). This might not be the best way to do it and I'm trying to figure out if there's a better function/module out there I should look into.

```
python
   for line in file:
       newHTML.write(re.sub(var1,var2,line,flags=re.MULTILINE), end='')         
       newHTML.write(re.sub(var3,var4,line,flags=re.MULTILINE), end='')
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
newHTML.write(re.sub(var1,var2,line,flags=re.MULTILINE), end='')
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments
```

If I comment out this code, the rest of the program runs fine albeit without finding and replacing these variables.

Perhaps re.sub() doesn't go well with write()?

Comment: `write()` is not `print()` and it doesn't have `end=` . And it doesn't add `"\n"` at the end.

Comment: can't you put correct value when you write HTML first time? It could be easier to create data `Link:,www.google.com,GOOGLE` and use it to generate HTML .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says what the problem is: as @furas commented, `write()` is not the same as `print()`, and doesn't accept the `end=''` keyword argument. `file.write()` by default doesn't include newlines if you don't explicitly put any `\n`'s, so it should work if you change the line to:

```
newHTML.write(re.sub(var1,var2,line,flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Also, regex and HTML [aren't the best of friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)... Your case is simple enough that using regex is fine, but you mentioned looking for a better module to generate HTML. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748559/generating-html-documents-in-python) had some good suggestions in the answers. Notable mentions for creating HTML templates on there were [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) (Flask's default engine), and [yattag](http://www.yattag.org/).