# Can i generate html code using other coding languages?

Tags: php, html, mailchimp

So, I want to send mails using `Mailchimp`. To make the process of making those mailing faster, **I want to have a standard mailing template**.

I tried `.htacces` to write `PHP` in my `.html` file. Sadly, mailchimp does not read any other than the html code, and completely ignores the PHP.

**Is there a way to generate html code**, so I can do things as import data from my database and get that data to an html file without using php in the file itself?

Or is there maybe anyone who knows **a better way of doing things**?

Comment: PHP can output pretty much anything, so yes, you could generate the HTML for your mail with dynamically outputted data. But you'll have expand your question for anyone to give you specific help. What you have tried? What does your integration into Mailchimp currently look like?

Comment: @BrettGregson Il make sure to expand my question right away. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate HTML with other languages, such as Python
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748854/12149235
If you are having issues with MailChimp, there are a few alternatives, such as GetResponse, which isn't directly used with PHP etc, but can be integrated into web applications and so forth.