# Elegant way to skip processing script tag for shpaml

Tags: python, shpaml

I have started using excellent [shpaml](http://shpaml.webfactional.com). But soon hit problem that my js code inside script tags is also processed. Is there a way to configure/extend python shpaml, so that it will skip script or any tag for that matter which is configured for exclusion.

I know I can prefix pipe but that is not acceptable within my team. I too agree with it.

TIA

Comment: why not use external files it is the preferred way to include javascript?

Comment: @Xavier: we find using script tags (mostly after related html tag/sections) easier. We do have js files but those contain common utilities. Page specific scripts are in page, inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I forked shpaml for following

- Skip processing if script/style tag is detected
- if block inside such tag already prefixed with pipe, then processing as earlier

Hoping that author agrees to it. So answer to my own question.

Fork is here https://bitbucket.org/shon/shpaml_website

Answer (score 2):

Use the verbatim tag like so

```
script type="text/javascript" VERBATIM
    $(function() {
        alert("hello world!);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for alternate template languages such as [Is there a HAML implementation for use with Python and Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519671/is-there-a-haml-implementation-for-use-with-python-and-django)

Comment: Thanks. I did go through all the options mentioned there. shpaml is just what I want. Like it does not have overlap with template functionality which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
script type="text/javascript" src='/path/to/script' | {# #}
```